# Framework not found, when it is clearly there

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, scintilla

I want to try out Scintilla (in Cocoa), but XCode does not cooperate. I included the Scintilla framework at `scite337/scintilla/cocoa/ScintillaFramework/build/Release/Scintilla.framework` by right-clicking the target in XCode and selecting `Add Existing Frameworks..` and then `Add Others...`. This seemed to work, suddenly the compiler seemed to find the files because the files produced some parser errors (so it has to get compiled, right?). But after I solved these errors, I got a knew one:

> Framework not found Scintilla
>   Command /Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1

I did verify if the `Target Membership` of the framework was set to `required` and it was. I tried to set the header search path to the path of the framework as well, but that gave the same error. I have no idea how to proceed from here.

XCode 3.2.6, Mac OS X 10.6.8

Comment: curious why run such an old version of Xcode?

Comment: I've never used Xcode 3 but in 4, 5 and 6 there is framework search path which is normally set when the project is configured to use a framework.  perhaps it isn't in Xcode 3...

Comment: @trojanfoe Often, settings for newer XCode versions are supported in v3 as well, they just are somewhere else. Please tell me where it would be in 4, 5 or 6 and I'll have a starting point for my search. (It sounds a little like `Header Search Path` though.)

Comment: You should definitely upgrade to Xcode 5.1. The latest version is available for download at Mac AppStore on the member center.

Comment: @MaxMacLeod I'm on Mac OS X 10.6.8 so this is the latest version I can download. Registered Apple Developers who are (or have been) enrolled in a developer program can download XCode 4 for Snow Leopard from the member center, but I am not enrolled in one (nor have I been).

Comment: @ArtemAbramov Not sure if you got a notification as well. I agree with you, I definitely should. I definitely want to, but I can't.

Comment: Why don't you upgrade your OS X as well, by the way, 10.6 is quite legacy, and Mavericks is free.

Comment: See this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/IncludingFrameworks.html

Comment: @ArtemAbramov My iMac is too old. I am really excited about Mavericks and Swift and ... and ... but I simply don't have the hardware.

Comment: @trojanfoe Thank you, that is indeed a better way to include a framework. It gives the same error though. My guess is it has something to do with relativity of paths (the path of the framework being resolved from the build directory, but not from the source directory). (The path to the framework is absolute, though, and `path type` is set to absolute.)

Comment: Use `$(SRCROOT)/../Whatever` to specify a directory relative to the current project root.

Comment: @trojanfoe I can't type in a path, I have to select it with the Finder-like browser. The absolute path is correct though, so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Oh well that's changed in Xcode 4+ as framework/header/library paths are set using a list of (somewhat awkward) text fields...

Comment: @ArtemAbramov I could upgrade to Lion, by the way, but it isn't available through the App Store anymore and it isn't entirely clear how to get a copy.